# Node taking array out of req.params.id result

Tags: javascript, sql, arrays, node.js

I am having problem when I pass the node .get to show the result the array wraps the data result.

```
[
  {
    "book_id": 1,
    "title": "HARRY",
    "pages": "123",
    "image": ""
  }
]
```

Is there way to make the result show like this without array?

```
  {
    "book_id": 1,
    "title": "HARRY",
    "pages": "123",
    "image": ""
  }
```

This is code for node to fetch data from sql.

```
app.get('/books/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    db.get_individual([req.params.id], function(err, individual) {

        if(err) res.status(500).send(err);

        else res.send(individual);
    });
});
```

This is the Sql query

```
SELECT * FROM book;
```

Comment: Use `res.send(individual[0]);`

Comment: Can't you just use `res.send(individual[0])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the object at `[0]`:

```
res.send(individual[0]);
```

Comment: I thought I did this but maybe my brain got little fried and missed it.
Thanks.